# MySql | table autonumber reverting to zero over time

Tags: mysql, autonumber

I have a MySql 5.1.52 database with a table which has consistently forgotten its autonumber sequence and then subsequently started from 1 again. It can take hours, days or weeks for this reset to occur.

Some have suggested that its related to clearing the table, that being empty it is unable to maintain its autonumber. Performing a few tests of my own to prove this theory failed. The table remembers its autonumber sequence even when cleared of all rows.

Do you know why this could be happening ?

Comment: Paragraph 2 appears to contradict paragraph 1. I'm confused. If the error persists after performing a REPAIR, please provide a SHOW CREATE for the problem table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB tables reset their autoincrement to MAX(auto_inc_column)+1 when the server starts. If the table is empty it resets to 1.

Comment: Thanks. As the server was hosted with third party I couldnt test restarting it. For methods to work around this issue, there is a discussion here --> http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16602/prevent-reset-of-auto-increment-id-in-innodb-database-after-server-restart